# Chrome Dev Tools Device Mode & Cookies

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools

In testing a site using the Chrome's Device Mode I've encountered some issues with cookies.

**The Setup**

I'm building my site on my local machine using Vagrant. The site uses a content management system ([Craft](http://buildwithcraft.com)) and I have the site in offline mode, requiring me to be logged into the CMS control panel in order to view the site. If I'm not logged a coming soon page will be displayed.

**The Issue**

Everything works fine in normal testing. I log into the Craft control panel, then pull up the homepage in a different tab at localhost:1111.

The issue arises when I switch to [device mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode), the refresh the page. I'm taken to the 'coming soon' page. If I go to the tab where I'm logged into the Craft control panel I'm notified that I've been logged out.

Watching the cookies for the domain I see 3 cookies containing some session data when logged into the control panel, and on the tab viewing the website (in normal viewing mode, not device mode). As soon as I switch to device mode (and refresh) one of the cookies is deleted, which results in the 'coming soon' page.

The cookies have a similar format:

- HASHhashHASHhash
- HASHhashHASHhashusername

The former of these is deleted upon refreshing.

Why does refreshing the site in device mode cause one of the cookies to be deleted?

Comment: Kinda hard to know for sure without seeing what Craft itself is doing for session management. It *could* be that they are checking the UA to be extra-secure with request forgeries. So, refreshing could cause Craft to see an emulated UA of another device type,which would make them invalidate the cookie on the next request. Typically in any systems I've worked in, this kind of thing isn't an issue. So I would think it more specific to Craft being extra secure over a direct DevTools issue.

Comment: Good point. I did try opening a tab, switching to device mode, logging into the control panel, and then opening another tab in device mode to visit the site. That seemed to work if I remember correctly. Annoying but understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with device mode.

Setting the following in `/craft/config/general.php` fixed the issue for me.

`'requireMatchingUserAgentForSession' => false`